# Is it possible to 'freeze pane' in WPF datagrid

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

Is it possible with a WPF datagrid to do like in Excel and Freeze the first few columns so that they always appear

If so how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the property `FrozenColumnCount`.
If you set it to 2 for example, then you can scroll the `DataGrid` horizontally but the first two columns will always be visible

```
<DataGrid FrozenColumnCount="2" ...>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try: `DataGrid.FrozenColumnCount`.